# Python DataFrame Loop through an element and assign a value

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, dataframe, iteration

Here, in my code, the correlation matrix is a dataframe and diag is a list.
When I run the following code (CholDC part at the bottom), it returns `numpy.float64` object is not iterable.
What do I need to do to make this code work?

```
def CholDC (correl, diag):
    for column in correl:
        j = 0
        for j in correl[str(column)][j]:
            Sum = correl[str(column)][j]
            k = int(column)-1
            if k >= 1:
                Sum = Sum - correl[str(column)][k]*correl[str(j)][k]
            else:
                Sum = Sum
            if int(column) == j:
                if Sum <= 0:
                    print ("Should be PSD")
                else:
                    diag[int(column)] = np.sqrt(Sum)
            else:
                correl[str(j)][int(column)] = Sum / diag[int(column)]

diag = []
df_correl = pd.DataFrame(df_correlation)
CholDC(df_correl, diag)
```

Comment: Some sample data would help

Comment: Please describe or show with data (current and desired results) what you are attempting as there might be pandas methods you can use instead of these `for` and `if` calls.

Answer (score 0):

To loop through a dataframe, you need to use iterrows(). See the example below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100, size=(10, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))

print(df)

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    print(row['B'], row['C'])

#dataframe output

    A   B   C   D
0  53  60  63  44
1  17  12  20  55
2  85  28  76  99
3  39  75  69  30
4   2  85  21   3
5  22   5  45  33
6  78  65  22  38
7  14  99   0  67
8  18  70  53  19
9  54  25  96   7

#output from loop

60 63
12 20
28 76
75 69
85 21
5 45
65 22
99 0
70 53
25 96
```

So use iterrows() in your code instead of `for column in correl`.